# Can PhantomJS page.open call a web service?

Tags: phantomjs

I have a PhantomJS script.  It runs a set of tests.  When the tests are done I want to record the results by calling a webservice.  I can't find any examples or people talking about calling a webservice with the page.open method. How would I do that?

Thanks for any pointers!

EV

Answer (score 0):

Here are this list of [page.open](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open-url.html) overloads

> open(url, callback) {void}
>
> open(url, method, callback) {void}
>
> open(url, method, data, callback) {void}

**Method** and **data** allow you to request a url with methods other than GET.

For example:

```
var data = {
    'user': 'username',
    'password': 'password'
};
page.open('http://www.google.com/', 'POST', data, function(status) {
    console.log('Status: ' + status);
    // Do other things here...
});
```

Another example is also available [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/post.js).

Please note, this only allow you to invoke a web api, not a Soap-like web service.